# React Redux combineReducers function calls my reducers 2 times when its exported and an additional time in the createStore function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm fairly new to Redux and I'm trying to understand why is the combineReducers function calling the reducers twice.

My reducer/index.js looks like this

```
  import {combineReducers} from "redux"

const AReducer = (state = "A", action) =>{
    console.log("In A reducer")

    switch (action.type){
        case "Alpha":
            return state + action.payload
        default:
            return state
    }
}

const BReducer = (state = "B", action) =>{
    console.log("In B reducer")
    switch(action.type)
        {
            case "Beta":
                return state + action.payload
            default:
                return state
        }
}

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    A : AReducer,
    B : BReducer
})

export default allReducers
```

and my store/index.js looks like this

```
import {createStore} from "redux";
import allReducers from "../Reducer"


const store = createStore(allReducers, 
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )

export default store
```

And the console log is displaying this

```
index.js:4 In A reducer
index.js:4 In A reducer
index.js:15 In B reducer
index.js:15 In B reducer
index.js:4 In A reducer
index.js:15 In B reducer
```

I only want to understand why it's behaving like this. I want a better grasp around what's going on in the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, let's print the `action`.

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';

const AReducer = (state = 'A', action) => {
  console.log('In A reducer, action: ', action);

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'Alpha':
      return state + action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const BReducer = (state = 'B', action) => {
  console.log('In B reducer, action: ', action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'Beta':
      return state + action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const allReducers = combineReducers({
  A: AReducer,
  B: BReducer,
});

const store = createStore(allReducers);
```

The logs:

```sh
In A reducer, action:  { type: '@@redux/INIT3.j.l.q.g.r' }
In A reducer, action:  { type: '@@redux/PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTIONn.x.t.b.s.j' }
In B reducer, action:  { type: '@@redux/INIT3.j.l.q.g.r' }
In B reducer, action:  { type: '@@redux/PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTIONu.8.f.5.c.h' }
In A reducer, action:  { type: '@@redux/INIT3.j.l.q.g.r' }
In B reducer, action:  { type: '@@redux/INIT3.j.l.q.g.r' }
```

**Explanation**

I use `AReducer`'s logs to explain, `Breducer` is also the same.

`combineReducers` function calls [assertReducerShape()](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/db0d9681cedea543da3f647e4b379945b9438476/src/combineReducers.ts#L152) function internally.

`assertReducerShape()` function will invoke each reducer passed in the `combineReducers` function with a [init action](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/db0d9681cedea543da3f647e4b379945b9438476/src/combineReducers.ts#L66) to check if the reducer has a valid returned value. This is how `In A reducer, action:  { type: '@@redux/INIT3.j.l.q.g.r' }` log come.

And, it also invokes each reducer with [unknown actions](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/db0d9681cedea543da3f647e4b379945b9438476/src/combineReducers.ts#L79) to check if the reducer return the current state for any unknown actions unless it is `undefined`. This is how `In A reducer, action:  { type: '@@redux/PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTIONn.x.t.b.s.j' }` log come.

When calling the `createStore` function, it will [dispatch init action](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/c21ac204e8ef1d6d428ee3b906b3646c73aa9441/src/createStore.ts#L359). So that every reducer returns their initial state. This effectively populates the initial state tree. This is how `In A reducer, action:  { type: '@@redux/INIT3.j.l.q.g.r' }` log come. This process is mentioned in the documentation, See [tips](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore#tips).

Also take a look at the `INIT` and `PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTION` action types in [utils/actionTypes](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/c21ac204e8/src/utils/actionTypes.ts#L11) file.

```
const randomString = () =>
  Math.random().toString(36).substring(7).split('').join('.')

const ActionTypes = {
  INIT: `@@redux/INIT${/* #__PURE__ */ randomString()}`,
  REPLACE: `@@redux/REPLACE${/* #__PURE__ */ randomString()}`,
  PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTION: () => `@@redux/PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTION${randomString()}`
}
```

*These action types are private, and used by redux internally,  you don't need to handle them. You will see the dispatched `INIT` action in redux dev tools, don't be surprised.*